# Sinatra and Ruby forms

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I apologise that this is very basic but I am new to writing Ruby. I'm trying to send a simple form to my posts page but I do not know how to retrieve it.

Here's my app.rb

```
#app.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'shotgun'
Tilt.register Tilt::ERBTemplate, 'html.erb'

get '/' do
  @title = "Home Page"
  erb :index
end

post '/post' do
  body = params[:body]
  erb :post
end
```

And here's my index.html.erb

```
<h1>Wiki</h1>

<form action="/post" method="post">  
  <input type="text" name="message">  
  <input type="submit">  
</form>
```

Do I need to add something to views posts page?

Answer (score 0):

You are just using the wrong key for the params variable.
A simple way to see what is being passed in the params variable in the request is to put something like:

```
#app.rb
before do
  puts '[Params]'
  p params
end
```

Then you can see in the terminal what is being passed.